# Randomly selecting rows and updating another table per row in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 10 and I'm looking to randomise some data.

I start by creating a temporary table and fill it with 1,000 rows of random data.

I then want to merge that into another table that may have less or more rows than the random data.

For each row in my dimension table I want to select a random row from the random data in the temporary table, setting the values in the dimension table to the randomly selected rows values in the temporary table.

eg.

I have a table called **reference.tv_shows** with the fields **Name** and **Category**.

I have a temporary table called **random_tv_shows** with the fields **Name** and **Category**. This data is completely random and consists of 1,000 rows.

I want to go through EACH row in the **reference.tv_shows** and pick a random row in the **random_tv_shows** table and set the **reference.tv_shows** Name and Category to be that of the selected row in **random_tv_shows**.

I tried running a fairly simple select but it looks as though it evaluates itself once then updates (Or maybe RANDOM() is only random once per TX?).

```
UPDATE reference.tv_shows SET "Name" = (SELECT "Name" FROM random_tv_shows ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
```

Is there a way to do this in postgres?

Comment: You did forget to explain what you are trying to do (in a clear way), You just told what you are doing, not what you have, and what you want to get.  Please add sample input, and desired output (like in: [mre])

Comment: @Luuk Wow, really? I'm quite surprised. I figured that it was quite clear but obviously not. I'll try and fix it so that it's easier to understand...

Comment: @Luuk I suppose it depends how you read it. I could re-phrase it a little bit as it may come across like I am suggesting "I tried this and it didn't work" but really I was trying to ask "How would I do this?". Let me re-phrase :)

Comment: So, you are really (trying to) pick a **random** row from a table that has **random** values (`random_tv_shows`) ?

Comment: @Luuk Yep. Hopefully that's a bit clearer. Apologies :)

Comment: First you have created the temporary table `random_tv_shows` with ramdom values only so basically in a random order by default. Then when you execute `SELECT "Name" FROM random_tv_shows`, the resulting rows are selected in a random order by postgres. So finally having an explicit random order for your query sounds like useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have a `test` table, with the field `a` which is an integer,

If I do this:

```
update test set a=random()*1000;
```

If wil get random values for every record in my table.

But when I do this:

```
update test set a=(select random()*1000);
```

All values for `a` will be the same.

This is shown in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=44af5eea37b06ded29840cf742a877f8)

Because, when updating the table `reference.tv_shows`, you only want 1 tv_show to be updated, you need to have a unique identifier for every tv_show. currently that info is not available in the question.

EDIT: I tried to reproduce your data (less records, and lack of imagination on categories, but... ).

When you have a unique id in your tables you can do:

```
UPDATE tv_shows 
SET Name = rts.Name,
    Category =  rts.Category
FROM tv_shows ts
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () R, Name, Category 
            FROM random_tv_shows
            ORDER BY RANDOM()) rts on rts.R = ts.id
WHERE tv_shows.id = ts.id
```

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=824a79e9befe36cf947cee38f14dc121)

Comment: Haha, bingo! Thankyou. Sorry I didn't provide any data. I thought it might be *quick* thing but it looks as though it was a bit more complex and some data may have helped. Thankyou again.

Comment: I am working on a similar task and wondering how to update each row without a common unique id between both the tables.

Comment: @NishantGhodke: When you have a new question, please ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)